# How to identify angular config errors easily

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am wondering if there is any `ng command` to help me identify any `angular.json` or any configuration related mistakes.

Because of I am too busy fixing other outdated npm packages, only recently I noticed that this `angular.json` is not what it is supposed to be like v15 after I compared it with a new v15.04.

But there is no report of anything wrong on `ng version` or `ng update`. But I do have to somehow keep `core.js` on v2.x which is used by `src/polyfills.ts` which is removed by angular since v8.

I can probably manually make the change. But I wonder why Angular does not update angular.json for me. And I fear there are other stuff that I missed.

[image]

Comment: `angular.json` is just one of those files you get used to manually updating. E.g. to add a new configuration or to do fileReplacements. Worst case is create a project with ng new and compare. The *why* is simple...because no one has written to code to do that